# Polymer switch between nested templates via 2-way binding

Tags: javascript, templates, polymer, shadow-dom, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a polymer element which has conditional templates to be rendered based on a polymer variable called 'size'

```
<template>
    <!-- icon fonts. Please do not move -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="meteocons/css/fontello.css">

    <template if="{{size == 'half'}}">
        <div fit layout center vertical>
            <h1 class="weather-value">{{temperature.F}}&deg;{{unit}}</h1>
            <i class="{{icon_single}} weather-icon-single"></i>
            <h3 class="weather-location">{{city}}, {{state}}</h3>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template if="{{size == 'triple'}}">
        <div fit layout center vertical>
            <h1 class="weather-value">{{temperature.F}}&deg;{{unit}}</h1>
            <i class="{{icon_single}} weather-icon-single"></i>
            <h3 class="weather-location">{{city}}, {{state}}</h3>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template if="{{size == 'quadro'}}">
        <div class="nam-weather-logo"><h5>NAM-weather</h5></div>
        <div class="forecast-time"><h5>{{currTime}}</h5></div>
        <div layout horizontal center-justified>
            <h3 class="weather-location">{{city}}, {{state}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div layout horizontal center-justified><h5 class="weather-sub-title">5-Day Weather Forecast</h5></div>
        <div layout horizontal center-justified>
            <template repeat="{{day in forecast}}">
                <div layout vertical center class="forecast-day">
                    <h1 class="weather-value-forecast">{{day.day}}</h1>
                    <i class="{{day.weather_icon}} weather-icon forecast"></i>
                    <h1 class="weather-value-forecast">{{day.weather_condition.maxtempF}}&deg;F</h1>
                    <h1 class="weather-value-forecast low">{{day.weather_condition.mintempF}}&deg;F</h1>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

I handle an event where on the window resize, I change the 'size' polymer property based on width of the viewport.

```
rearrangeElements: function(){
        var polymer = this;
        var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

        //half size (icon)
        if(width <= 55){
            polymer.size = 'half';
        }

        if(width > 55 && width <= 168){
            polymer.size = 'regular';
        }

        if(width > 168 && width <= 300){
            polymer.size = 'double';
        }

        if(width > 300 && width <= 768 ){
            polymer.size = 'triple';
        }

        if(width > 768){
            polymer.size = 'quadro';
        }
    }
```

The right template renders on load and everythings peachy. However, when the resize event fires, and the variable changes, nothing happens.

I thought that when the size property would change, based on my template binding, the other template will get rendered, but I was 'epiclly' wrong. My question is how do I get polymer to switch between templates based on changing a 2-way bound variable?

Would appreciate any info at all on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up not using templates for the different views. Instead, I displayed each conditional view as a div, and set the css display property on each div to a polymer variable (see below)

```
    <div style="display:{{sizes.half}}">
        ...
    </div>

    <div style="display:{{sizes.regular}}">
        ...
    </div>

    <div style="display:{{sizes.double}}">
        ...
    </div>
```

And in my script, when I handle the screen change event, I just change the value of each property:

```
 polymer.sizes.half = 'none';
        polymer.sizes.regular = 'none';
        polymer.sizes.double = 'none';
        polymer.sizes.triple = 'none';
        polymer.sizes.quadro = 'none';

        //half size (icon)
        if(width <= 55){
            polymer.sizes.half = 'inherit';
        }

        if(width > 55 && width <= 168){
            polymer.sizes.regular = 'inherit';
        }

        if(width > 168 && width <= 300){
            polymer.sizes.double = 'inherit';
        }
```

It seems really simple, (too simple that it smells fishy) but it solves my problem. Hope this helps anyone who might experience the same issue I had.